# Pure CSS. Visibility of child elements depends on parent class. Is it possible?

Tags: css, visibility

Can I realize this behavior by **pure CSS**:
If parent block has "hidden" class it child elements with "a" class must be invisible

Example

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="a"></div>   //  Visible
    <div class="b"></div>   //  Visible
</div>

<div class="parent hidden">
    <div class="a"></div>   //  Invisible
    <div class="b"></div>   //  Visible
</div>
```

Comment: If you are using a behaviour, why you need a CSS solution provided you are trying to achieve something by script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 .parent.hidden .a 
 {
   ///display: none;
 }
```

**note:**

```
visibility:hidden hides an element, but it will still take up the same space as before. The element will be hidden, but still affect the layout.
```

and

```
display:none hides an element, and it will not take up any space. The element will be hidden, and the page will be displayed as if the element is not there
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply like this :

```
.parent.hidden .a { display: none; }
```

Note there is no space between `.parent` and `.hidden`.

Comment: I assume `visibility:none;` should be a better solution, but shall leave on the OP to decide.

Comment: @NathanLee Yes, this really depend on his usage :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

Try this:

```
.parent.hidden .a{visibility:hidden;}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/rNkLG/2/)

Comment: Read what the OP has mentioned on the first line. _If parent block has "hidden" class_. So I assume it should be inside the parent. I may be incorrect about his percepetion, but his sentences convey the same. Just an observation. Its OP wish at the end. - @Hiral

Comment: `.hidden .a{visibility:visible;}`?? Are you sure?? - @hiral

Comment: Hey that was just my observation, I may be wrong about the OP's perception, but his sentences convey the same. So you can answer what you feel ideal, just that I pointed my observations - @Hiral

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

Add the below to your CSS.

```
   div.parent.hidden .a{visibililty:hidden;}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `div.parent.hidden`??

Comment: Yes. It should be. I have edited the above. Thanks for the mention. - @Hiral

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a normal contextual selector:

```
.hidden .a { visibility: hidden; }
```

If you actually meant removing the element from rendering, instead of making it invisible (a rather different thing), then you would use `.hidden .a { display: none; }`.

It would, however, be illogical and confusing (to people reading the HTML source) to use a class name `hidden` for an element that is not itself meant to be hidden. A name like `hidelinks` might be better.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

.parent .a, .hidden .a{ visibility:hidden;}